# Android ArrayAdapter sort() method on Listview keeps old row data unchanged

Tags: android, sorting, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` in my android app that does sorting. For example, when I clicked Name, it sorts by name.

**Here is the code:**

```
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {
    private final ArrayList<Person> people;
    //.......
            public void sort(SortBy x) {
        switch (x) {
            case NAME:

                this.sort(new OrderByName());
                sortedBy = "NAME";
                break;
```

---

**Here is the Comparator:**

```
    private static class OrderByName implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person s1, Person s2) {
        return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
    }
}
```

When I click `Name` to sort the listview by name.. I got the list sorted but the old row of data still remains.. and associates with another row...
I am fairly new to Android... And I really need some help on debugging this issue. Thanks in Advance!

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting the list, just use the notifyDataSetChanged() method to your ArrayAdapter object. It will refresh the list. I'm assuming, you're not creating more than one ArrayAdapter object.

//notify that the list changed adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your ArrayAdapter have latest values in it.If it is updated with latest values used below :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify the listview to update items in the list.
```

Hope these helps you.